# How to have any unavailable function names as index() get parameters in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In codeigniter, How can i automatically take any unavailable function name as a URL parameter of `index()` ?  Example.  If i have `index()` and `say_hello()` in my controller i want to be able to get `some_param` as URL parameter in `index()` when i call `localhost/some_param`, but also maintain calling `localhost/say_hello` as a function.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the _remap() function:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping